# How do I configure ASP.NET to use MongoDB for storing user names

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET project that uses MongoDB.  The ASP.NET project comes with an automatically generated user login system.  The system is initially configured to use a sql database.  It is a black box however; inspecting the methods only yields metadata.

As far as I can tell, the only way to manipulate the database used is from the configuration file (is this incorrect?).  I would like to configure the Accounts controller to store the user id and password in my MongoDB, testdatabase.

Here is the current configuration:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
    requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
...
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
              type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
...
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication1-20150805041852.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication1-20150805041852;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <!--add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/testdatabase" providerName="" />-->
</connectionStrings>
```

I spoke to another developer, and it seems that this might or might not be a trivial fix, involving some tricks...

Comment: Can you modify the application source code? You're not going to simply be able to do this from configuration.

Comment: Yes I can...I'm new to ASP.NET.  I'd use something else, but I want to build my libraries in F#.  I have a working mongodb site...but it is mysterious how the user login is handled. Is there something else going on between the code and the database, besides the configuration file?

Comment: You'll have to look at the code for yourself and determine what's going on. There's no magic, you just need to look at it and find out.

Comment: You should read this link https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/

Comment: Going to close this soon (unless someone objects) as I no longer have any idea why I was asking this, and would have no idea what to do with the answer. 2017